# How to implement __delitem__ and __delslice__ in C[++]?

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7

I am implementing a Python 2.7 module in C++. I need to define a class (let's call it `Attr`) which will support these operations:

```
a = Attr()

# some code ...

x = a[7]       # must have
x = a['foo']   # must have
del a[4]       # must have
del a[5:12]    # should have
del a[5:12:3]  # could have
```

For the getters, I added a `PyMappingMethods` object to the `tp_as_mapping` member of the `PyTypeObject` used for `Attr`. In there, I have a function registered in `mp_length` and `mp_subscript`, and this works fine.

But I have no idea how to implement the deletions (not even the single-index one). `PyMappingMethods` only has one more data member, `mp_ass_subscript`. The documentation mentions that this is used by `PyObject_SetItem()`, which (according to its [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/sequence.html#PySequence_SetItem)) implements `o[key] = v`.

There is no mention in any documentation I could find ([official 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html) or Google) of hooking a C/C++ function for use by `PyObject_DelItem()`, `PySequence_DelItem()` or `PySequence_DelSlice()`. How can I implement these in my C++-implemented object?

I would like to provide all 3 variants of item deletion, but I could live with just plain `del a[4]` if necessary. I don't want to support `del a['foo']`, but I believe I could handle that on the C++ side if the only way is to support both constructs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I look into code and It looks like `PySequence_DelItem` is using `mp_ass_subscript` with third argument `NULL`:

```
PyObject_DelItem(PyObject *o, PyObject *key) {
    ...
    m = o->ob_type->tp_as_mapping;
    if (m && m->mp_ass_subscript)
        return m->mp_ass_subscript(o, key, (PyObject*)NULL);
    ...
```

Deleting with slice will pass SliceObject as a key.

Answer (score 0):

Look at whichever function you're using to implement `mp_ass_subscript`. Inside the function, add a check for whether `value` is null. If it is, call `PyObject_DelItem(dict, key)` rather than `PyObject_SetItem(dict, key, value)`. For instance:

```
int my_dict_set_value_via_key(PyObject* self, PyObject* key, PyObject* value) {
    if (!value) {
        return PyObject_DelItem(self, key);
    } else {
        return PyObject_SetItem(self, key, value);
    }
}
```